# Angular JS How to get post data for every fields

Tags: angularjs, forms, post

I know how to get data from a post with ng-model, just assign an ng-model value to each fields and you can get it from the $scope.

But how to get every fields values from a post without knowing each single field?

I mean something like $_POST variable in PHP where you get every data fields in an array.

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<form data-ng-submit="sendPost()" ng-model="test.formData">
...
</form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.sendPost = function () {
   //This doesn't work
   console.log($scope.test.formData);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question by putting exact example and requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a $resource factory and use it to save any kind of form data

```
angular
    .module('myApp.services', [])
    .factory('ResourceService', function($resource) {

        var ResourceObj = $resource(
                'v1/model',
            {
                id: '@id' 
            },
            { 'update': { method: 'PUT'} }
        );

        // class methods
        ResourceObj.getEmptyTemplate = function () {
            return {
                'name': '',
                'website': ''
            };
        };

        return Obj;
    });
```

your controller will look like

```
angular
    .module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, ResourceService) {
        $scope.resourceObj = new ResourceService(ResourceService.getEmptyTemplate());

        $scope.saveResource = function() {
            console.log($scope.resourceObj);
            $scope.resourceObj.$save({}, function (resourceData) {
                //success message
            });
        }; 
    });
```

your form html will look like

```
<form role="form" name="resourceObj" data-ng-submit="saveResource()">
    <input type="test" data-ng-model="resourceObj.name">
    <input type="test" data-ng-model="resourceObj.website">
    <button type="submit" data-ng-disabled="!resourceObj.$valid"></button>
</form>
```